# to run php file in background

Tags: php, sql, command-line, fork, daemon

i want to run code in background..i want this while downloading huge report which takes lot of time.. i have gone through almost all google sites but still m not able to find the answer.. m actually stuck not able to move further..

the code m using to download report in xls is

```
<?php

include '../dbConnect.php';
$from1='2013-06-01';
$to1='2013-07-01';
$today=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$fileName='Outbound_download'.$today.'.xls';
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

//echo 'Testing connection handling in PHP';


header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");


$flag = false;
$query="";
$query  = "SELECT pendingCustomer.ackNo AS RAF, pendingCustomer.serialNo AS Serial_No, pendingCustomer.phoneNo AS Phone,pendingCustomer.repairStatus as ArrivalStatus,tblRepairQueue.repairStatus as CurrentStatus, pendingCustomer.savedAt AS UpdateRecievedAt, pendingCustomer.updated as Updated, pendingCustomer.status as Status 
FROM pendingCustomer,tblRepairQueue
WHERE pendingCustomer.status!='' AND DATE(pendingCustomer.savedAt)  BETWEEN  '".$from1."' AND  '".$to1."' and pendingCustomer.ackNo=tblRepairQueue.ackNo";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

 while($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) ."\r\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
      echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
  }




?>
```

i want this excel code to run in background. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why not persist the status of the excel generation to a database table? BTW, time limit of 0 is pretty dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

To run a PHP file on the background, you must put your code in one file and call the PHP interpreter to run it on the background. On a *nix server, use `exec( '/usr/bin/php -f path/to/your/script > /dev/null &' );`. Check the path to the PHP interpreter on your server, it might be something else than `/usr/bin/php`, ask your hosting provider if necessary. On a Windows server, use `pclose( popen( 'start /b C:\php\php.exe -f path\to\your\script' ) );` (again, assuming that php.exe is in `C:\php`).

The background process, however, cannot output anything to the user's browser, since it's running on its own. One way to accomplish what you need would be to output the PHP results in a file, set some flag when the job is done, and in another script check if the results are ready and give a link to the file for the user.

Comment: Good luck with that on a shared host.

Comment: Tried & tested :) Depends on the host.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher will /usr/bin/php be constant always

Comment: @namratha No. You can try `$path_to_php = trim( shell_exec( "which php" ) );` or rely on the `PHP_BINDIR` constant. But caution! Neither of these works on a Windows host.

Comment: @HeikkiU m not getting u.. becoz i dont have any idea abt this.. can u give the code

Comment: @namratha Most hosts don't allow access to `exec` and similar functions, that was my point, not the location of PHP.